# How to split a string into multiple strings if spaces are detected (GM:Studio)

Tags: string, split, game-maker

I made a console program, but the problem is that it doesn't allow parameters to be inserted. So I'm wondering how would I split a single string into multiple strings to achieve what I need. E.g.: `text="msg Hello"` would be split into `textA="msg"` and `textB="Hello"`

This is the main console code so far (just to show the idea):

```
if (keyboard_check_pressed(vk_enter)) {
    text_console_c = asset_get_index("scr_local_"+string(keyboard_string));
    if (text_console_c > -1) {
        text_console+= "> "+keyboard_string+"#";
        script_execute(text_console_c);
        text_console_c = -1;
    }
    else if (keyboard_string = "") {
        text_console+= ">#";
    }
    else {
        text_console+= "> Unknown command: "+keyboard_string+"#";
    };

    keyboard_string = "";
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is any simply way for GMS to handle delimiters. I would however do the following: Search the string for number of spaces (number of words - 1). For each substring delimited by the spaces add each character up to the space, essentially creating each string from the line. Use those separate strings as your arguments in your script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may help, haven't tested it out but if you can follow what is going on its a good place to start.

```
Text = "msg Hello"
counter = 0
stringIndex = 0
for (i = 0; i < string_length(text); i++)
{
    if string_char_at(text,i) == " "
    {
        counter++
        stringIndex = 0
    } else {
        string_insert(string_char_at(text,i),allStrings(counter),stringIndex)
        stringIndex++
    }
}
```

allStrings should be an array containing each of the separate strings. Whenever a " " is seen the next index of allStrings starts having it's characters filled in. stringIndex is used to add the progressive characters.

Answer (score 2):

I cant recommend spliting string with iteration by char, because when u try split very very very long string, then time to split is very long and can freeze thread for a short/long time. Game maker is single threaded for now.
This code is much faster.

string_split

```
var str = argument[0] //string to split
var delimiter = argument[1] // delimiter
var letDelimiter = false // append delimiter to each part
if(argument_count == 3)
    letDelimiter = argument[2]
var list = ds_list_create()
var d_at = string_pos(delimiter, str)
while(d_at > 0) {
    var part = string_delete(str, d_at , string_length(str))
    if(letDelimiter)
        part = part + delimiter
    str = string_delete(str, 1, d_at)
    d_at = string_pos(delimiter, str)
    ds_list_add(list, part)
    if(d_at == 0 && str != "")//last string without delimiter, need to add too
        ds_list_add(list, str)
}
return list;
```

Dont forget `ds_list_destroy` after you iterate all strings
for example:

```
var splited = string_split("first part|second part", '|')
for(splited) {
//do something with each string
}
ds_list_destroy(splited)
```